# Submit form interfering with others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this email subscribe form for newsletter which gets delivered to me by email using `PHP`. It is located in footer which means that it is available on all pages across the website.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbMh5/)

Form works ok now but the problem is that it is interfering with other parts of website where forms are included - it messes those up and causes error to show on other fields as well.

My question is how do I isolate this form and script only for this part of the code so it will be defined only for this part of the webpage? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do more than one of your forms, or form elements, have the same id? E.g. are there multiple #subscribe or #email or #send elements on the page?

Comment: How exactly is it "interfering with other parts of the website where forms are included"? This could mean a number of things.

Comment: #subscribe is used only here but #email and #send are used in other forms yes but isn't #subscribe tag in JS suppose to isolate this ?

Comment: You cannot re-use IDS, they must be unique.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Is there no way to wrap this in a <div> or something? So basicly every form across the website must have different id="" ?

Comment: I recommend changing the #email ids to classes. Then change the $("#email").addClass("error") calls to $("#subscribe .email").addClass("error")

Comment: Every element on a page must have a different id (or no id at all). Multiple elements can have the same class, though.

Comment: @JasonReid Can you post example of chaging IDs to classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments above,, you need to replace the "id" attributes in the html with "class" attributes. Then, modify your jQuery finders to search by class, constrained within the #subscribe form.

The HTML

```
<form id="subscribe" name="subscribe" action="#" method="post">    
  <input name="email" type="email" class="email" placeholder="Your e-mail adresss"> 
  <span><button class="send" type="button">Subscribe</button></span>
</form>
```

And the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subscribe").submit(function () {
        return false;
    });


    $("#subscribe .send").on("click", function () {
        $('#subscribe input.error').removeClass('error');

        var emailval = $("#subscribe .email").val();
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
        if (mailvalid == false) {
            $("#subscribe .email").addClass("error");
        }

        var minlen = $('#subscribe input[minlength]').filter(function(){
            return this.value.length < +$(this).attr('minlength')
        }).addClass('error').length;

        if (mailvalid == true && minlen == 0) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<p><strong>Sending, please wait...</strong></p>");

            $.ajax({
               //you shouldn't need to change what you had here in the Fiddle; I didn't
               //copy it for brevity's sake
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Because it doesn't work for me...http://jsfiddle.net/K5L29/

Comment: I had one typo I corrected. Also, my code didn't include your validateEmail function, which you do still need. http://jsfiddle.net/DwNLh/

Comment: Thanks. Btw, what would be the best way if I want to use this script for another form submission on one part of the website. The difference is that this other form has more than 1 inputs to submit but can use same php.